# css table centering in IE11 but not in Chrome/Firefox

Tags: css

Have a header, two buttons and two tables in my Html.
When webpage is first launched table associated with 'first' button is displayed. The table associated with second button is not displayed.

When 'second' button is clicked, table associated with second button is displayed and the first table is not displayed.

The code works fine in IE11 and the table is centered as desired in IE11; but the table does not get centered in chrome/firefox.

### HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>All Stock Data</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stock.css" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="stock.js" ></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <h1>Stock Data</h1>

    <div class="mytoggle"> 
      <button onclick="toggleDisplay('first')" id="button_first">First</button>
      <button onclick="toggleDisplay('second')" id="button_second">Second</button>
    </div>

    <table id="first">

        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Color</th>
          <th>Shape</th>
        </tr>



        <tr>
          <td>O1</td>
          <td>Blue</td>
          <td>Square</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>L1</td>
          <td>Brown</td>
          <td>Circle</td>
        </tr>

    </table>

    <table id="second">

        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Color</th>
          <th>Shape</th>
        </tr>



        <tr>
          <td>H2</td>
          <td>White</td>
          <td>Round</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>M2</td>
          <td>Gray</td>
          <td>Square</td>
        </tr>

    </table>

  </body>
</html>
```

### CSS:

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: auto;
}

table#first {
  display: block;
}
table#second {
  display: none;
}
```

### Javascript:

```
function toggleDisplay(myTableId)
{
  if(myTableId == "first"){
     document.getElementById('first').style.display = "block";
     document.getElementById('second').style.display = "none";

     /*background*/
     document.getElementById('button_first').style.background = "blue";
     document.getElementById('button_second').style.background  = "gray";
  }


  if(myTableId == "second"){
     document.getElementById('first').style.display = "none";
     document.getElementById('second').style.display = "block";

     /*background*/
     document.getElementById('button_first').style.background = "gray";
     document.getElementById('button_second').style.background  = "blue";
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CSS** (replace the one that's there):

```
table#first {
  display: table;
}
```

Script:

```
function toggleDisplay(myTableId)
{
  if(myTableId == "first"){
     document.getElementById('first').style.display = "table";
     document.getElementById('second').style.display = "none";
  }
  if(myTableId == "second"){
     document.getElementById('first').style.display = "none";
     document.getElementById('second').style.display = "table";
  }
}
```

In short, everywhere you set a `<table>` to display as `block` you are getting hosed. A `<table>` is not block. So use `display:table`. More info [going back to CSS 2](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#display-prop).

Comment: Updated CSS and javascript to replace display: block with display: table. Now the table is centered in Chrome and firefox. In IE11 the table associated with 'first' button is centered, BUT when I click on 'second' button to display second table at that point I get no table displayed.

Comment: Have tested again in IE11, and it works for me. Check for a typo. Do you have a JSFiddle / CodePen?

Comment: Created first JSFiddle. Fixed typo, to remove unnecessary </a>. But no luck beyond that, yet-  https://jsfiddle.net/dlamar/daujazyu/1/

Comment: Getting a JS error there. Made a CodePen in IE11: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qZewNK

Comment: I see the CodePen works as desired. Next I made a local copy(3 files - html/css/js) and just added  the <html> <head> and <body> tags like in the original post, IE11 still does not display when I click on second button. Chrome is fine.  But obviously it works for you...

Comment: Yep. IE11 (Win10 and Win8.1). No errors in debugger. Buttons change color, table swaps. Any plug-ins messing with stuff? Bad references? Special characters inserted on paste? Any errors in the F12 dev tools?

Comment: I have IE 11.09600.18314 ; and I have the problem on that version. I tried 11.09600.18015, that version worked fine and no issues there, I can see the table on 'second' button click.

Comment: Yeah, being unable to reproduce it here means I can't offer much more help for that specific browser. Suggest searching for bugs, though that is really specific. And odd.

Comment: I understand will keep looking around. Thanks for all  the inputs.

Comment: Good luck. And if you feel compelled to accept my answer (because it seems like it works except for that one instance of IE11), keen. If not, well, ok.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, found the reason why table was not centering. So far I was bringing up the html page locally(right clicking on file and selecting open in browser) without going through the web server. Once I started accessing the html file through the web server, then the tables started centering as desired. Other features like alternate row highlighting also started working in IE(which was also not getting triggered for my case).